# How can i get input after some time without press any key in golang

Tags: go

I have an app that is running and after 5 second , i want to get all text that the user writed without press any key like enter . In Golang

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function `readInput` that uses a `time.Timer` to wait for a certain time for the input of the user

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func readInput() string{

    state, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("setting stdin to raw:", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := terminal.Restore(0, state); err != nil {
            log.Println("warning, failed to restore terminal:", err)
        }
    }()

    timer := time.NewTimer(2 * time.Second)
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input := []rune{}
    go func() {
        for {
            
            r, _, err := in.ReadRune()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("stdin:", err)
                break
            }
            input = append(input, r)
        }
    }()
    <- timer.C
    return string(input);
}

func main() {
    s:= readInput()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: Because there is a timer of 2 seconds in the answer. You need to adjust it to what suits you